# Regex for OSX resolution

Tags: ruby, regex, macos, screen-resolution

I'm using this command to get the screen resolution:

```
system_profiler SPDisplaysDataType | grep Resolution
```

This returns your screen resolution of the form:

```
Resolution: 1366 x 768
```

The problem that I'm being faced with, is finding a way to get the values: `1366` and `768` separately by possibly using a regex in Ruby. The reason why I need to get these two values is so that I can use them here:

```
image = Image.new(x, y)
```

where `x` and `y` would be `1366` and `768` respectively. My question is how can I those two values by themselves?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
matches = str.match(/(\d+) x (\d+)/)
hor = matches[1]
ver = matches[2]
```

Comment: Use `str[/(\d+) x (\d+)/]; hor, ver = $1, $2`

Answer (score 1):

You could also do:

```
x, y = str.scan(/\d+/)
```

Comment: Use `/\d+/` instead, and you won't need to flatten the result.